# How to add wordwrap for ChoiceElement in the ChoiceGroup while developing GUI using Java ME?

Tags: user-interface, java-me, midlet, cldc

While developing GUI using Java ME- I get the wordwrap for the text being shown on ChoiceGroup, but the text on the ChoiceElement doesn't get shifted to the new line if the length of the text exceeds the size of screen. How can we get the wordwrap for the text being shown on the ChoiceElement?

Answer (score 0):

```
choiceGroup = new ChoiceGroup("choiceGroup", Choice.MULTIPLE);
choiceGroup.append("A long text that needs text wrapping", null);
choiceGroup.setFitPolicy(Choice.TEXT_WRAP_ON);
```

Comment: This one Wraps the text on the Choice Group. But for long texts on the ChoiceElement doent get wrapped. Actually it's fine when executed on Emulator, but when deployed to N70 the ChoiceElement long text is broken.